# Automatically loading layers on startup (problem) using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I made a small code to fetch some PostGIS layers into QGIS and apply them with qml style, like the following:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(#CONN_INFO)

city_filter = 'Cairu'

uri.setDataSource("public", "dende_mp", "geom", f"nom_munici = '{city_filter}'")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), f"car_{city_filter}", "postgres")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
vlayer.loadNamedStyle('C:\\Users\\curyp\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projetos\\project_1\\styles\\tam_area_car.qml')

uri.setDataSource("public", "sigef_visita", "geom", f"municip = '{city_filter}'")

vlayer_sigef =  QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), f"sigef_{city_filter}", "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer_sigef)
vlayer_sigef.loadNamedStyle('C:\\Users\\curyp\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projetos\\project_1\\styles\\tam_area_sigef.qml')
```

It's working fine, but for some reason after I close and reopen QGIS, these same layers get loaded again, with styling and all. It also asks me if I want to save or discard project modifications.
I've tried to delete layers, discard editings, calling `QgsProject.instance().removeAllMaplayers()`, but none of these works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be dealing with a bug rather than a problem that other users can help with. Consider installing a different version of QGIS, and using a new profile and see if you can replicate the issue. If you can, perhaps raise a bug (https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html)

Comment: Check "startup.py" file in your home folder (something like ..AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3). Code in this file runs automatically on QGIS start. Check PYQGIS_STARTUP environment variable also.

Comment: When and where are you executing the code?